# Swift2: Cannot subscript a value of type '[GKScore]?'

Tags: ios, swift

`let highscore = leaderboardRequest.scores[0] as! GKScore`

results to

`Cannot subscript a value of type '[GKScore]?'`

What is the correct syntax in Swift2

Comment: I code for my kids so I lack Swift vocabulary. What's unwrapping?

Comment: I've made an answer with details.

Comment: @user594883 unwrapping is take the real value (not nil) out of an optional value (can be nil), using as! to unwrapping will cause crash if that value is nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let highscore = leaderboardRequest.scores?[0] as! GKScore
```

even better:

```
if let highscore = leaderboardRequest.scores?[0] {
    //your code
}
```

Or:

```
guard let highscore = leaderboardRequest.scores?[0] else { return }
```

Answer (score 3):

`leaderboardRequest.scores` is not unwrapped, unwrap it before using subscript.

```
if let scores = leaderboardRequest.scores {
    if let highscore = scores.first as? GKScore {
        // safely use `highscore` here
    }
}
```

"unwrapping" is a key concept in Swift, it goes with Optionals.

The `?` part in `[GKScore]?` means that this is an Optional. It contains either a value or nil. An Optional is not the type it holds, you have to "extract" the value from the Optional, it's called "unwrapping".

To safely unwrap the value from an Optional, use "if let" as I did, or "guard" which appeared in Swift 2, or optional chaining, etc. There's a lot of different techniques.

All this is explained in the Swift Basics Apple ebook and documentation site.